# Insert users into Active Directory

Tags: python, sql-server, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to determine how to best insert users into active directory from a SQL server table.

I figured I could use the LDAP sever to do a insert, but the research iv done would suggest otherwise and that I could only pull data from active directory to SQL server.

Then I thought I could use a python program to query the table and spit out a CSV file to then  do a bulk insert but I am not sure if this would modify existing users if data changes.

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general idea of the algorithm:

1. Load user data from SQL Server
2. Convert it into an [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) (LDAP Data Interchange Format) file
3. Import the LDIF file into Active Directory using the [LDIFDE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731033%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command-line tool

Python, or any other programming language, can help you with step 2. Notice that the details of the conversion are very specific to how your data is represented. You'll have to carefully map each data base field into an LDAP attribute, and determine the classes to be used in the LDAP objects.

Will the above modify existing users? yes, of course. You could write the LDIF in such a way that it updates the existing data, or if that's a problem you could verify first if an user exists in the Active Directory and don't add those changes to the LDIF file.

**Alternatively**

You could use [CSVDE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732101%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for importing data in CSV format, but anyway you'll have to design a mapping strategy for each one of the fields that you want to import into Active Directory.

Comment: That's right. It's the appropriate format for exchanging information in AD, but you'll have to do some serious programming for this data migration to succeed. Good luck!

Comment: Alternatively, I was also thinking about using c# and creating a stored procedure

Comment: The programming language is not _that_ relevant for the problem at hand, what matters is how you're going to represent the extracted data - in a way that's easy to import in AD